# Is there a way in Sitecore to display a link to a media library item that the user does not have access to?

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore7.5

I want to use Sitecore security to make access to certain documents on a site require registration/login.  However the client would like to show links to these documents to anonymous users as a way to let them know that if they register/login then they will get access to these protected documents.

Is there some simple way to do this in Sitecore?  The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to use some sort of Security Disabler to get the list of documents and display the links on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas Therkildsen suggests, you can use the Security Disabler, although Sitecore's preferred method is to use a user switcher.

```csharp
using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(userWithMoreRights))
{
    // ...
}
```

`SecurityDisabler` basically gives the code the right to do anything it wants, whereas `UserSwitcher` is more restrictive.

See the [Security API cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf) for more information.

Comment: To clarify Martin, switching to a User means their permissions can be controlled in the Content Editor; giving that user to access all Media except those that contain sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SecurityDisabler:

```csharp
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    //code to get links
}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  I was hoping there might be a better way. :)  Thanks for answering.